# It is possible/productive enough to TDD in C++ projects?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tdd, testability

I want to know if anyone of you guys use TDD in your c++ projects and how it performs compared to managed languages like C# and Java.
And what frameworks you guys are using to automate tests on c++ projects?

Comment: UnitTest++ is what I've used for a majority of my projects.

Comment: Check out this series of videos on C++ and TDD: http://www.vimeo.com/album/254486/video/13240481

Answer (score 2):

Two useful C++ test frameworks that don't seem to have been mentioned yet are [`Boost test`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) and [`Google Test`](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/).

Answer (score 1):

Test Driven Development is possible in any language. You need the right testing tools and methodologies for the language, and may possibly need a custom testing infrastructure for your project.

I have found CppUnit (at least 1.x) to be a very poor framework -- it seems to use Java/C# idioms in a C++ language and does not have support for STL constructs.

If you want a good example of Test Driven Development (in C), look at the Wine project -- http://test.winehq.org/data/ shows their test results across the different versions of Windows, Wine and the different commits into the Wine repository. They have their own custom test infrastructure.

Comment: Note that while people continue to use CppUnit, the original author (Michael Feathers) did a complete rewrite, briefly explained in _Working Effectively with Legacy Code._ His revised approach makes clever use of macros, which you can see in CppUTest, UnitTest++, and googletest.

Answer (score 1):

I recently moved from a C# project that was developed using TDD to a project that is using C++.  I was dreading it quite a bit, but I find that doing C++ with TDD is a lot more enjoyable and the code is more robust than I remember from past (non-TDD) experiences with C++.

We are using Google Test.  It is not as easy to use as NUnit/MbUnit, but it seems to work pretty well.  There is also a Google mocking framework http://code.google.com/p/googlemock , but I have not been using that yet.